My URL requests are timing out for a locally deployed app
I'm trying out deploying a new ML code for a course I'm doing. I'm deploying the model via flask/gunicorn through a docker to test locally.
The docker run (docker run -it --platform linux/amd64 --rm homework_test) seems to work well.
[2024-06-16 10:04:10 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 22.0.0
[2024-06-16 10:04:10 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:9696 (1)
[2024-06-16 10:04:10 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-06-16 10:04:10 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8

But when I run the Test.py function on a separate terminal it "times out" (not sure if that is the correct terminology?). I've included the full error message below as I'm not sure which steps I should take to debug this.
I've already checked that the ports match so that cant be the issue. However, I will include the dockerfile, predict, and test files below too just in case.
(base) marcusleiwe@Marcuss-iMac homework % python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 791, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 497, in _make_request
    conn.request(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 395, in request
    self.endheaders()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1289, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1048, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 243, in connect
    self.sock = self._new_conn()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 218, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10fb438d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 845, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9696): Max retries exceeded with url: /predict (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10fb438d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcusleiwe/Documents/GitHubRepos/mlops-zoomcamp/cohorts/2024/04-deployment/homework/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    requests.post(url, json=year_month)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9696): Max retries exceeded with url: /predict (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10fb438d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

Dockerfile
FROM agrigorev/zoomcamp-model:mlops-2024-3.10.13-slim

RUN pip install -U pip #just make sure the pip version is correct
RUN pip install pipenv

WORKDIR /app
COPY ["Pipfile", "Pipfile.lock", "./"]
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy

COPY ["predict.py", "./"]

EXPOSE 9696

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "--bind=0.0.0.0:9696", "predict:app"]

predict.py (abridged)
import pickle 
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify 
import pandas as pd 
import os 
with open('model.bin', 'rb') as f_in: 
     dv, model = pickle.load(f_in) 

app = Flask('duration-prediction') 
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST']) 
def predict(): 
    .... 
    y_pred = model.predict(X_val) 
    df_result = pd.DataFrame({ 'predicted_duration': y_pred }) 
    results = { 'mean_duration': df_result['predicted_duration'].mean() } 
    return jsonify(results) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=9696)

test.py
import requests

year_month = {
    "YEAR" : 2023,
    "MONT": 5
}

url = 'http://localhost:9696/predict' 
requests.post(url, json=year_month)


You should add a healthcheck api for checking alive server. Timeout maybe caused by long process api. In docker container, it limit cpu and ram so the perfomance will lower than in local run

You need a docker run -p option for the container process to be accessible from the host.  That has two port numbers.  In your test.py, the port number in the URL matches the first number; the second number matches the port 9696 that the server process is listening on.

What is the difference between ports and expose in docker-compose? - Stack Overflow

Thanks @DavidMaze. I appreciate the answers and tips the -p was indeed what was wrong

And also thank you @furas for the additional information on the function of EXPOSE.

Every container has own IP address and you may have to use this IP in test.py
When I run container with Flask (without Gunicorn)
docker run flask-port-test

then Flask shows me
http://172.17.0.2:9696

and it works for me in web browser, but http://localhost:9696 doesn't work.
And it doesn't even need EXPOSE.
And docker ps -a shows PORTS 9696/tcp

To use localhost:9696 in test.py it needs option -p
docker run -p9696:9696 flask-port-test

If you use -p8000:9696 then you may use localhost:8000 in test.py
And docker ps -a shows PORTS 0.0.0.0:8000->9696/tcp, :::8000->9696/tcp

Doc EXPOSE

The EXPOSE instruction doesn't actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports.


The docker inspect IP address is only usable on one specific Docker configuration (directly using the Docker engine on native Linux); it doesn't work on Docker Desktop, for example.  The docker run -p path works more broadly and doesn't need the additional lookup.
